# Size of training in Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

I just started getting involved with Machine Learning and I decided to create a spam filter for my social app, using the Naive Bayes classifier. I'm following this guide: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-a-simple-spam-detecting-machine-learning-classifier-4471fe6b816e

My app has ~70,000 posts and about 3,000 of them are marked as spam. How many of my **non**-spam posts should I use to train my model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimal case/control ratio in a case-control study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25740/optimal-case-control-ratio-in-a-case-control-study)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you do stratified sampling to create training/test splits; otherwise your priors will be biased. Specifically, in Naive Bayes, you *estimate* class priors from data. If the prior is $3/70$ and you choose to equally include spams and non-spams, your prior estimate will be $\pi=0.5$, which can easily harm your predictions. A typical train/test split can follow 80/20 convention.

Comment: So I should include all of my spam and non-spam posts in the training process?

Comment: no, separate $80 \%$ of your samples for training, and $20 \%$ of them as test set, both for spam and non-spam.

Comment: 80% of my whole database, right?

Comment: yes, if you include 80 % of your spams and 80 % of your non-spams for training, the training set will be 80 % of your whole dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much!